# CGImage from CAMetalLayer

Tags: ios, macos, core-graphics, calayer, metal

I've set up a custom iOS UIView that displays a list of layers, one of which is a `CAMetalLayer`. I was trying to paint that same content to an image in a `CGContext`. I tried to extract the layer's contents in order to build a `CGImage`, but couldn't find a good path.

First, I've tried to asynchronously extract the contents of the framebuffer with a `addCompletedHandler()` callback, but the async nature of the callback didn't behave nicely with `CGContext`.

I've also tried extracting the contents of the `CAMetalLayer` by using the `layer.contents` property, but apparently the type of the `contents` is `CAImageQueue`, which has no documentation or exposed through the API.

I've also tried rendering the layer directly to the `CGContext` like so:

```
layer.render(in: cgContext)
```

but that didn't bear any results either.

Lastly all I'd need to do is retrieve the bytes making up the layer texture, and I could build my own `CGImage` from scratch.